# Any tools to see which http handlers are called?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get a captcha web control to display, but it isn't going into the HttpHandler that I created. This isn't my project and it is quite big so I'm not sure what is going on. Is there any tools or techniques to see which handler is being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that handler is not registered in web.config? If you can debug it, set breakpoint in ProcessRequest method.

Comment: Yup that was the case. Previous user was using IIS 7 and I was using built in vs 2010 server and it uses II 6

Comment: VS server don't use IIS6, but it don't honor IIS7 configs, so you are half right.

Comment: VS uses it's own webserver called 'Cassini'

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Trace.axd? It should list which modules and handlers get called if I recall correctly.

Comment: Forgot all about trace. Is there a custom style for the trace? The black and white contrast is pretty bad

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, could pretty easily greasemonkey it I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will show you every request your browser makes.

Comment: No.  The handler is a function of the IIS pipeline.  fiddler will debug HTTP traffic b/t you and the server

Comment: I did try fiddler and it only showed a redirect, but not the handler that was accessed

Answer (score 0):

Add in your handlers:

```
Debugger.Launch()
```

If this handler execute then debugger start.

Comment: Is this the same as running vs with debugger? If so, I tried that, but couldn't figure out which handler file it was going into. It's a big project and everything is all over the place.